# Readmore link on Blogger visible but not active in mobile view

Tags: css, mobile, blogger

I'm having an issue on my blogger theme, where when viewing the site on my mobile, the "read more" link is visible but not clickable.  I noticed when I turned my phone sideways into landscape mode, the link becomes clickable.  I would appreciate any help in trying to figure out what to fix - thank you so much!

The website is here: https://www.outoftouchstone.com

Pastebin to the full theme: https://pastebin.com/4hfDvnwh

Here's a snippet of possibly relevant code:

```
     @media only screen and (max-width:480px){
        #outer-wrapper {
          padding:0 8px;
        }
.containz {
width: 365px;
}

a.readmore {
display: block ;
}



#footer-socials {

    height: 300px;
}

#nav {
    width: auto;
}
div#header-inner {
    margin-left: 0;
}
div.conty {
width: 256px;
}



#searchformfix, #header-right {
display: none;
}
.pagenavi span,.pagenavi a {
margin-top:3px;
}
.top-comment{width:37%}

        .top-comment-widget-menu{height:58px}
        ul.xpose_thumbs1,ul.xpose_thumbs22{width:100%}
        #menu-main {
          display: none;
        }
        #sidebar-narrow{display:none}
        div#mywrapper {
          float: center;
          width: auto;
        }
        .header, .header-right, .stylebox,.stylebox1  {
          float:none;
          width:100%;
          max-width:100%
        }
        .header img {
          margin: 0px auto 0;
        }
        .largebanner .widget, #bottombar {
          padding:8px;
        }
        .post, .breadcrumbs {
          margin:0 0 8px;
          padding:8px;
        }
        .stylebox .widget-content,.stylebox1  .widget-content {
          padding:8px;
        }
        h2.post-title, h1.post-title {
          font-size:16px;
        }
.img-thumbnail, .img-thumbnail img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 15px !important;
}
        .img-thumbnail {
          margin:0 8px 0 0;
        }
        #stylebox-1 .widget, #stylebox-3 .widget,   #stylebox-2 .widget, #stylebox-4 .widget, #stylebox-5 .widget, #stylebox-6 .widget {
          padding:0 0 8px 0;
        }
        .comments .comment-block, .comments .comments-content .inline-thread {
          padding:10px !important;
        }
        .comment .comment-thread.inline-thread .comment {
          margin: 0 0 0 0 !important;
        }
        .footer-left, .footer-right {
          float:none;
          text-align:center;
        }
div#top-social {
   float: none; 
    text-align: center;
}
      }
 @media screen and (max-width:360px){
.header h1.title {font: bold 54px Fjalla One,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;padding-top: 6px;}
    }
      @media screen and (max-width:320px){
.containz {
    width: auto;
}
        #outer-wrapper {
          padding:0 6px;
        }
        #menu-main {
          display: none;
        }
        #sidebar-narrow{display:none}
        div#mywrapper {
          float: center;
          width: auto;
        }
        .post, .breadcrumbs {
          padding:6px;
        }
        .stylebox .widget-content,.stylebox1  .widget-content {
          padding:6px;
        }
  #bottombar {
padding: 8px 0;
width: 288px;
}
#bottombar h2 {
    padding: 15px 0px 10px;
}
      }

@media screen and (max-width:319px){
.header h1.title {font: bold 44px Fjalla One,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;padding-top: 11px;}
#selectnav1 {
    width: 220px;
}
#outer-wrapper {
    padding: 0px;
}
.containz {
    width: auto;
}
        #outer-wrapper {
          padding:0;
        }
        #menu-main {
          display: none;
        }
        #sidebar-narrow{display:none}
        div#mywrapper {
          float: center;
          width: auto;
        }
        .post, .breadcrumbs {
          padding:6px;
        }
        .stylebox .widget-content,.stylebox1  .widget-content {
          padding:6px;
        }
#bottombar {
    padding: 8px 0px;
    width: 220px;
}
.PopularPosts .item-title {
    padding-bottom: 0.2em;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 1.3em;
}
        .PopularPosts ul li img {width: 52px;height:52px;}
      }
    </style>
```

Comment: your sidebar is overlaying on top of your content thats why its not clickable

Answer (score 0):

I inspected the elements using Chrome's dev tools.

As Gene said that the sidebar is getting overlapped with your content.

While inspecting the sidebar element, I found that you are using `float: none` in the media query with `max-width: 768px`.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px)
#post-wrapper, #sidebar-wrapper {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

By removing the line `float: none` from above media query will fix the overlapping issue while adding some space between the sidebar and the content and you'll be able to click on the 'Read More' links.

But then it will apply `float: right` (which doesn't really affect anything).

I hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I actually can't find that bit of code in my theme. I wanted to check if that is the code you meant?